# Suddenly, menu bar applications have blue badges

Tags: mojave, menu-bar, malware

I am using a MacBook Air 13' bought in 2017, running Mojave 10.14.1 (18B75). I recently removed malware and plugins named Weknow.ac. Now, several of the application badges and indicators in the menu bar appear with a blue background. I've tried different things to remove the background color, mainly by upgrading and re-installing the apps affected, but nothing seems to work. Any help would be much appreciated.

Examples include;

NTFS for Mac (gear icon on the top right corner)

[image: NTFS for Mac]

Google BackUp And Sync (three dots on the top right corner)

[image]

CleanMyMac X (local storage disk drive icon on the top left corner)

[image: CleanMyMac X]

Comment: When you click on the affected icon in the third example, does it open into a preferences or other kind of application settings window? The gear and triple vertical dots icons in the first two examples typically denote these kinds of actions in the interface.

Comment: Thank you for your concern, IconDaemon. Every button seems to be working fine and doing exactly what it is supposed to be doing once clicked. Moreover, the same blue background appears in the cancel badge ('X') in operations like copying files.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/jmUSTh4

Comment: any of the original Apple app do that ?

Comment: @Buscar Haven't noticed anything unusual in other Apple applications with respect to the background color except for the Finder window on copying file that you can see above.

Answer (score 2):

I see the same thing for Google Drive. Blue around the dots. I don't think this is a problem with your system, more that the highlight color selected in Preferences is being added to a menu item because of the way the company coded the app. Some apps are great at integrating (e.g. Dropbox, which went to great lengths to get a custom sidebar icon) and others are not (e.g. Google, which has weird bugs like this in the display of some apps).

Comment: What I don't understand is that it didn't happen before. It suddenly affected every application also including the finder 'cancel' icon when copying files.

Comment: Could be a weird display bug... but it at least doesn't seem to be malware-related. Possibly something that changed with the 10.14.1 update?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have the Appearance in the System Preference > General selected as Blue.

[image]

Try switching to Gray if you like it better.

Comment: I could not replicate his issue changing that option, but maybe is a display bug and it will work.

Comment: The Appearance section in System Preferences > General, lists Light and Dark in Mojave. I've tried changing both and it didn't work, the blue background persists.

Comment: I do not have Mojave I used High Sierra